# Understanding Python property working

Tags: python, properties

From one of the blogs, I have the following code, which I am using to understand the working of python `property`.

```
class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, temperature = 0):
        self._temperature = temperature

    def to_fahrenheit(self):
        return (self.temperature * 1.8) + 32

    @property
    def temperature(self):
        print("Getting value")
        return self._temperature

    @temperature.setter
    def temperature(self, value):
        if value < -273:
            raise ValueError("Temperature below -273 is not possible")
        print("Setting value")
        self._temperature = value
```

Q1: Under the `__init__` method, why is the author using `self._temperature`. Should it not be `self.temperature`? How will the control go to `@temperature.setter`?

Comment: I hope you run this under python 3, on python 2 you need to inherit your class from `object`.

Comment: "How will the control go to `@temperature.setter`?" - it won't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether it is correct to use `self._temperature` in `__init__()` is sometimes a matter of taste. In essence there is now a third method (apart from the `setter` and `getter`) that knows about the attribute the actual value is stored. IMO that is not nice, and could lead to errors if you refactor the class and change the attribute, but it is not incorrect per se.

There can be situations that the setter already assumes a value is stored in some other way. Not here, but e.g. when the `self._temperature` should only be set if it were increased. In that case you have to directly access the attribute. (This situation can be circumvented by testing for the "storage" attributes existence using `hasattr(self, "_temperature")` within the setter and getter and initialising appropriately).

There is never a point where the control goes to the setter. The setter gets used if you do:

```
 self.temperature = some_value
```

you can always directly set the "hidden" attribute (in this case `self._temperate`) from any of the other methods (or directly accessing the attribute on an instance of `Celsius`). Please note that this just happens to be the property name with an underscore before it, it could be any (free) name.